# Running xdotool movewindow from a python script

Tags: python, ffmpeg, xdotool

I am writing a python script to run a movie using ffplay, and then move the ffplay window to a specific location on the screen.

The script I am basing this one is located here - http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577376-simple-way-to-execute-multiple-process-in-parallel/

The only difference is I am changing the commands array at the bottom to

```
commands = [
    ['xdotool', 'search', '--name', 'Goodfellas', 'windowmove', '480', '200'],
    ['ffplay', '-x', '320', '-y', '180', '-autoexit', '/data/media/Vidoes/Movies/Goodfellas.mp4']
]
```

The video plays fine, but the window will not move position

To test if the script is actually cycling through all the commands I added the command

```
['xdotool', 'mousemove', '180', '180'],
```

And the mouse will indeed move to location 180, 180 on my screen

Perhaps maybe ffplay takes a split second to load and there is still no screen called Goodfellas when the movewindow command is executed

Answer (score 0):

If you are only using one window or one instance of ffplay, then try using

```
 ['xdotool', 'search', '--class', 'ffplay', 'windowmove', '480', '200']
```

instead